How to link a shape to a column so when the shape gets larger the column get larger too?
I want to do a database on Excel and in the first page there is a navigation menu on the left side working with macros for each tab to send the user to this exact tab. The code is the following and works.
Sub menuNav()
Dim menu As String
menu = Right(Application.Caller, Len(Application.Caller) - Len(Left(Application.Caller, 4)))
'MsgBox menu
Application.Sheets(menu).Select
ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Select
End Sub

I would also like to make the menu workable, so if the user click on a button, the menu is slim and only show the icons for each tab, however, if the button is clicked again, the menu get larger and shows both the icons and the texts. I found a way with this code from this video : https://youtu.be/T6pRSAZXKpQ?si=J-cphOCsxDux8VZ-
Option Explicit

Dim P1      As Worksheet
Dim xMenu   As ShapeRange
Dim i       As Double
Dim x1      As ShapeRange
Dim x2      As ShapeRange
Dim x3      As ShapeRange
Dim x       As Double
Dim y1Top   As Double
Dim y3Top   As Double
Dim l       As Double
Dim btA As ShapeRange
Dim btD As ShapeRange

Private Sub CreateObjects()

Set P1 = ActiveSheet
Set xMenu = P1.Shapes.Range("MenuPlan")
Set x1 = P1.Shapes.Range("r1")
Set x2 = P1.Shapes.Range("r2")
Set x3 = P1.Shapes.Range("r3")
Set btA = P1.Shapes.Range("btAugmenter")
Set btD = P1.Shapes.Range("btDiminuer")

End Sub

Sub IncreaseEffects()

Call CreateObjects

btA.Visible = msoFalse
btD.Visible = msoCTrue

x = x1.Left

For i = 48 To 35 Step -0.4
    DoEvents
    xMenu.Width = i
    x1.Left = x - 0.4
    x2.Left = x - 0.4
    x3.Left = x - 0.4
    
    x = x - 0.4
Next i

P1.Shapes("txt_Page d'accueil").TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.Visible = msoTrue

x = x1.Left
l = 19

For i = 35 To 170 Step 20
    DoEvents
    xMenu.Width = i
    
    x1.Left = x + 20
    x2.Left = x + 20
    x3.Left = x + 20
    
    x = x + 20
    
    x2.Width = l
    
    l = l - 3.3
    
    x1.Rotation = 135
    x3.Rotation = -135
    
Next i

y1Top = x1.Top + 6.1222
y3Top = x3.Top - 5.69032

x1.Top = y1Top
x3.Top = y3Top
x = x1.Left

For i = 170 To 180 Step 0.3
    DoEvents
    xMenu.Width = i
    
    x1.Left = x + 0.3
    x2.Left = x + 0.3
    x3.Left = x + 0.3
    
    x = x + 0.3
    
Next i

End Sub

Sub ReduceEffects()

Call CreateObjects

btA.Visible = msoCTrue
btD.Visible = msoFalse

x = x1.Left

For i = 180 To 193 Step 0.3
    DoEvents
    xMenu.Width = i
    x1.Left = x + 0.3
    x2.Left = x + 0.3
    x3.Left = x + 0.3
    
    x = x + 0.3
Next i

P1.Shapes("txt_Page d'accueil").TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.Visible = msoFalse

x = x1.Left
l = 0

y1Top = x1.Top - 6.1222
y3Top = x3.Top + 5.69032

x1.Top = y1Top
x3.Top = y3Top

For i = 193 To 58 Step -20
    DoEvents
    xMenu.Width = i
    
    x1.Left = x - 20
    x2.Left = x - 20
    x3.Left = x - 20
    
    x = x - 20
    
    x2.Width = l
    
    l = l + 3.3
    
    x1.Rotation = 0
    x3.Rotation = 0
    
Next i

x = x1.Left

For i = 58 To 48 Step -0.3
    DoEvents
    xMenu.Width = i
    
    x1.Left = x - 0.3
    x2.Left = x - 0.3
    x3.Left = x - 0.3
    
    x = x - 0.3
    
Next i

End Sub

Now, in order for my project to work, I would like the navigation menu to be linked or be part of a column, so when the menu change size, the other columns don't get impacted from it.

I didn't follow all the code you gave, just the basic idea (and I don't like the code, but this is StackOverflow, not CodeReview).
Assuming that your "menu" shape starts at the very left of the sheet (.left = 0), all you need to do is to adjust the column width of the first column (=A) so that it gets the same width as the menu shape.
Unfortunately, it is not so easy so set the exact width of a column - that's because the column width can be changed only using the property ColumnWidth which uses a different unit than Width.
Easiest way is to figure out the correct column width for the small and the large menu. For your large menu width (180), that's approx. 33.5, and for the small width, it's approx 8.5.
So add the statements
Sub ReduceEffects()
    ...
    P1.Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 8.5
End Sub

Sub IncreaseEffects()
    ...
    P1.Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 33.5
End Sub

But those values might be wrong - either play with them or use a function that tries to set the columnWidth property according to the width property of the menu shape. However, that's not that easy. I tried it by calculating the ratio between the ColumnWidth and the Width of a cell and use that to calculate the columnWidth from the menu width, but that's not working precisely. According to This answer on SO, you need to do this three times until it's precise enough.
Sub setMenuCellWidth()
    Dim i As Long
    With P1.Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn
        For i = 1 To 3
             Dim f As Double
             f = .ColumnWidth / .Width
            .ColumnWidth = xMenu.Width * f
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Now your code will be
Sub ReduceEffects()
    ...
    setMenuCellWidth
End Sub

Sub IncreaseEffects()
    ...
    setMenuCellWidth
End Sub

